# A sufficient condition to ensure a function to be linear

Tags: functions, continuity

Suppose that $f$ is continuously differentiable on $\Bbb R$, and $$\lim_{x\to +\infty}f'(x)$$
exists and is finite. Furthermore, $$f(x+1)-f(x)=f'(x),\ \forall\ x\in\Bbb R.$$
Show that $f$ is linear, that is, there exists constants $a,b$ such that 
$$f(x)=ax+b,\ x\in \Bbb R.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a=\lim_{x\to +\infty}f'(x)$. It is enough to prove that $f'(x)=a$ for all $x$. Fix any $x$. Let $X=\{y:f'(y)=f'(x)\}$. We will show that $\sup X=\infty$. Assume the contrary, say $\sup X=s<\infty$. Using that $f$ is continuously differentiable it follows that $s\in X$. Hence $f'(s)=f'(x)$ and $f(s+1)-f(s)=f'(x)$. By the [Mean Value Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) there is $c$ with $s<c<s+1$ and $f'(c)=f(s+1)-f(s)=f'(x)$. But then $c\in X$ and $c>s=\sup X$, a contradiction. This shows that $\sup X=\infty$. This implies that $f'(x)=a$, indeed given any $\varepsilon>0$ there is $z_\varepsilon$ such that $a-\varepsilon<f'(z)<a+\varepsilon$ whenever $z>z_\varepsilon$, in partucular taking $z>z_\varepsilon$ with $z\in X$ we have $a-\varepsilon<f'(x)<a+\varepsilon$. Taking $\varepsilon\to 0$ we obtain that $f'(x)=a$. Since $x$ was arbitrary, it follows that $f'(x)=a$ for all $x$, which clearly implies that $f(x)=ax+b$ (for some $b$).